# Exiting bash script without terminating ssh connection

Tags: linux, bash

I'm pretty new to bash scripting and I'm attempting to write a script that does some basic operations.

I want to check certain conditions and if they are met, terminate the script. So for example, I want to check whether the zip of files was successful:

```sh
echo "Zipping file..."
for file in $fileList;
    do
        echo $file | zip -v $archive -@
        if [[ $? != 0 ]];
            then
                echo "Error creating zip"
                exit 1
        fi
    done
```

What happens though is that the `exit 1` signal causes the ssh connection to terminate as well:

```
Zipping file...

Command 'zip' not found, but can be installed with:

sudo apt install zip

Error creating zip
Connection to 3.137.7.52 closed.
```

**What's the correct way to terminate a script without also disconnecting from the server?**

Comment: just `break` or `return` out of the loop instead

Comment: I would close this as a duplicate of [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/138730/exit-the-bash-function-not-the-terminal) or [this](https://serverfault.com/questions/405948/bash-script-exit-on-error-set-e-closes-putty-ssh-session), but that's on another site in the StackExchange

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it has been answered on several other SE sites.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you wrap it all in a script with shebang `#!/bin/bash` than `exit 1` will be fine
but if you run this as a oneliner directly in console then this `exit 1` means exit from console, and that would break ssh connection obvy

```
cat > ziper.sh << \EOF
#!/bin/bash
echo "Zipping file..."
for file in $fileList;
    do
        echo $file | zip -v $archive -@
        if [[ $? != 0 ]];
            then
                echo "Error creating zip"
                exit 1
        fi
    done
EOF

./ziper.sh
```

In oneliner use `break`